# Parse XML - Get attribute each value - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, xml-parsing

The parseXML code below return all the child values, I would like to set the key attribute to each value.

Code:

```
    function myFunction() {

  // This is the sample XML data
  var response = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><h:TrackingId xmlns:h="https://ntdbdt.com/ntd/v13">56453-45634-4634-4563-456</h:TrackingId></s:Header><s:Body><GetAccountsInfoResponse xmlns="https://fhnbdf.com/Customer/v13"><AccountsInfo xmlns:a="https://ndhnb.com/nf/v13/Entities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:AccountInfo><a:Id>654547</a:Id><a:Name>Test Outlet</a:Name><a:Number>F777TBZM</a:Number><a:AccountLifeCycleStatus>Active</a:AccountLifeCycleStatus><a:PauseReason i:nil="true"/></a:AccountInfo><a:AccountInfo><a:Id>6784576</a:Id><a:Name>Test Workshop</a:Name><a:Number>X6667</a:Number><a:AccountLifeCycleStatus>Active</a:AccountLifeCycleStatus><a:PauseReason i:nil="true"/></a:AccountInfo><a:AccountInfo><a:Id>64563</a:Id><a:Name>Test Shop</a:Name><a:Number>R666U96Q</a:Number><a:AccountLifeCycleStatus>Pause</a:AccountLifeCycleStatus><a:PauseReason>2</a:PauseReason></a:AccountInfo></AccountsInfo></GetAccountsInfoResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>';
  
  try {
  var document = XmlService.parse(response);
    var root = document.getRootElement();
    var atom = XmlService.getNamespace('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
    var entries = document.getRootElement().getChildren('Body', atom);

    if (entries) {
      _.each(entries[0].getChildren(), function(child) {
        accounts_list = child.getValue();
      });
    }
  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    throw new Error();
  }
  Logger.log([accounts_list])
  return accounts_list;
}
```

response:

```
[654547Test OutletF777TBZMActive6784576Test WorkshopX6667Active64563Test ShopR666U96QPause2]
```

I would like to get this response:

```
[
{id=654547, name=Test Outlet, number=F777TBZM, accountLifeCycleStatus=Active, pauseReason=}, 
{id=6784576, name=Test Workshop, number=X6667, accountLifeCycleStatus=Active, pauseReason=}, 
{id=64563, name=Test Shop, number=R666U96Q, accountLifeCycleStatus=Pause, pauseReason=2}, 
]
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tested with [setName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/attribute#setName(String))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var response = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><h:TrackingId xmlns:h="https://ntdbdt.com/ntd/v13">56453-45634-4634-4563-456</h:TrackingId></s:Header><s:Body><GetAccountsInfoResponse xmlns="https://fhnbdf.com/Customer/v13"><AccountsInfo xmlns:a="https://ndhnb.com/nf/v13/Entities" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:AccountInfo><a:Id>654547</a:Id><a:Name>Test Outlet</a:Name><a:Number>F777TBZM</a:Number><a:AccountLifeCycleStatus>Active</a:AccountLifeCycleStatus><a:PauseReason i:nil="true"/></a:AccountInfo><a:AccountInfo><a:Id>6784576</a:Id><a:Name>Test Workshop</a:Name><a:Number>X6667</a:Number><a:AccountLifeCycleStatus>Active</a:AccountLifeCycleStatus><a:PauseReason i:nil="true"/></a:AccountInfo><a:AccountInfo><a:Id>64563</a:Id><a:Name>Test Shop</a:Name><a:Number>R666U96Q</a:Number><a:AccountLifeCycleStatus>Pause</a:AccountLifeCycleStatus><a:PauseReason>2</a:PauseReason></a:AccountInfo></AccountsInfo></GetAccountsInfoResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>';

  var document = XmlService.parse(response);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var ns1 = root.getNamespace();
  var ns2 = XmlService.getNamespace("https://fhnbdf.com/Customer/v13");
  var accountInfo = root.getChild("Body", ns1).getChild("GetAccountsInfoResponse", ns2).getChild("AccountsInfo", ns2).getChildren();
  var accounts_list = accountInfo.map(e => e.getChildren().reduce((o, f) => (o[f.getName()] = f.getValue(), o), {}));
  console.log(accounts_list);
}
```

- When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

  ```json
  [
    {"Id":"654547","Name":"Test Outlet","Number":"F777TBZM","AccountLifeCycleStatus":"Active","PauseReason":""},
    {"Id":"6784576","Name":"Test Workshop","Number":"X6667","AccountLifeCycleStatus":"Active","PauseReason":""},
    {"Id":"64563","Name":"Test Shop","Number":"R666U96Q","AccountLifeCycleStatus":"Pause","PauseReason":"2"}
  ]
  ```

#### References:

- [Class XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)